# React Global Function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-context

I want to create a react javascript function to print messages in the HTML side. Think of it like `console.log` but printing to the page instead. I have read about: context & redux seem to help but was wondering if there was a better more straight forward way of doing this.

Comment: You need print message after application mounted?

Comment: Implement this functionality with React Context... You will save yourself lots of pain during passing props up and down across all of your components in the components tree.